# Flutter how to get material 3 tonal palettes

Tags: flutter, material3

Using the [material 3 theme builder custom](https://m3.material.io/theme-builder#/custom) colors we have 4 colors that we need to choose from: Primary, Secondary, Tertiary, Neutral.

The site then generates a full both light and dark scheme that is based on the colors.

[image]

After adding the material file to the app we can use them like that

```
Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary;
```

In the bottom part of the custom material 3 theme builder there is part about **tonal palettes** ✨

[image]

Would love to use the generated tonal palettes.

I have tried `Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary[50];` and `Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary.shade50;` but it does not work.

How can I use the material 3 generated tonal palette?.

Answer (score 4):

Answer:

The generated material 3 does not bundle inside of the Theme of the app as far as I know but the good news is that you can generate it yourself from each of your colors.

Add the following package: [material_color_utilities](https://pub.dev/packages/material_color_utilities)

Insert your primary color in `_primaryColor` to get the primary color tonal palette

```dart
    TonalPalette primaryTonalP = toTonalPalette(_primaryColor); 
    primaryTonalP.get(50); // Getting the specific color


    TonalPalette toTonalPalette(int value) {
      final color = Hct.fromInt(value);
      return TonalPalette.of(color.hue, color.chroma);
    }
```

And repeat for each main color in the material 3 colors

---

**Bonus:**

You can also generate all the material 3 theme in the app programmatically from 5 colors.

Neutral on the left is not the same as generated Neutral as shown in the image

[image]

You will need the following packages: [dynamic_color](https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_color), [material_color_utilities](https://pub.dev/packages/material_color_utilities)

Insert your values in `_primaryColor`, `_secondaryColor`, `_tertiaryColor`, `_neutralColor`, `_neutralVariantColor`

```dart
    import 'package:dynamic_color/dynamic_color.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:material_color_utilities/material_color_utilities.dart';

    ThemeData get themeData {
        List<int> colors = <int>[
          ...toTonalPalette(_primaryColor).asList,
          ...toTonalPalette(_secondaryColor).asList,
          ...toTonalPalette(_tertiaryColor).asList,
          ...toTonalPalette(_neutralColor).asList,
          ...toTonalPalette(_neutralVariantColor).asList,
        ].toList();
    
        ColorScheme colorScheme =
            CorePaletteToColorScheme(CorePalette.fromList(colors))
                .toColorScheme(brightness: brightness);
    
        return ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
          colorScheme: colorScheme,
        );
      }
    
    TonalPalette toTonalPalette(int value) {
        final color = Hct.fromInt(value);
        return TonalPalette.of(color.hue, color.chroma);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add [material_color_utilities](https://pub.dev/packages/material_color_utilities) pacakge

```dart
void createTonalPalette(BuildContext context) {
  
  // Generate palette for primary
  TonalPalette primaryTonalP =
      toTonalPalette(Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary.value);
  TonalPalette secondaryTonalP =
      toTonalPalette(Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary.value);

  TonalPalette tertiaryTonalP =
      toTonalPalette(Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiary.value);

  primaryTonalP.get(50); // Example how to use
}

TonalPalette toTonalPalette(int value) {
  final color = Hct.fromInt(value);
  return TonalPalette.of(color.hue, color.chroma);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answers, you could also write a handy extension on Color like this:

```
import 'package:material_color_utilities/material_color_utilities.dart';

extension Material3Palette on Color {
  Color tone(int tone) {
    assert(tone >= 0 && tone <= 100);
    final color = Hct.fromInt(value);
    final tonalPalette = TonalPalette.of(color.hue, color.chroma);
    return Color(tonalPalette.get(tone));
  }
}

// Usage
Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary.tone(50);
```

Comment: Cool will test it, it looks promising